# Shell script not exiting after a pipe to log file command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, exit

Please find the below scrip.
When i run it, ./myscript.sh I am getting all echo statements in the terminal as well as in my log file.
But after the execution it is not exiting or coming back to terminal
Please help. I am quiet new to scripting.

```
#!/bin/sh

process() {
echo "Start..."
echo "Stop..."
exit 10
}

until [ $? -eq 10 ];
do
process | tee -a /home/temp/myLog.log
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The exit code of a pipeline is the exit code of the *last* process in the pipeline.  So here, even if `process` exits with code 10, the whole pipeline `process | tee ...` will exit with code 0.

You can change this behaviour using the `pipefail` option

```
set -o pipefail
```

Now the exit code of a pipeline will be the last non-zero exit code of any of the piped processes, or 0 if they all exit successfully.

[This blog post](http://bclary.com/blog/2006/07/20/pipefail-testing-pipeline-exit-codes/) explains it nicely, the official reference is the last paragraph from [this section of the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try grabbing the result of the first part of the pipe with ${PIPESTATUS[0]}:

```
#!/bin/sh

process() {
echo "Start..."
echo "Stop..."
exit 10
}

result=0
until [ $result -eq 10 ]
do
   process | tee -a myLog.log
   result=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
   echo $result
done
```

Comment: Isn't that `bash` specific?

Answer (score 1):

Move the pipe behind the loop; the result is the same but the breaking will work:

```
#!/bin/sh

process() {
  echo "Start..."
  echo "Stop..."
  exit 10
}

until [ $? -eq 10 ]
do
  process
done | tee -a /home/temp/myLog.log
```

As others pointed out before me, the pipe's exit status is complex, so you cannot just use `$?` to get it.  Best solution seems to be to get rid of the pipe in the context you need the exit status.

Maybe you do not even need the `-a` anymore this way.

Comment: @rishimon I tried that as well and it works like a charm :)  No, honestly, what "does not come out"?  Is the script not coming out of the loop?  Is the output not coming out into the log file?  What do you observe instead?